# Clamav eternal suffer to update the version

Tags: clamav

How to upgrade clamav? When I use:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install clamav
```

with update enabled for any new version or for long support it does not update the program. What can I do to update clamav?

```
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.99.2 Recommended version: 0.99.3
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
daily.cvd is up to date (version: 24255, sigs: 1835431, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 319, sigs: 75, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
```

Comment: Did you read the link after "DON'T PANIC"? It answers your question.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running ? You might need to use a ppa, backports, upgrade ubuntu, or download direct from upstream, hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

**Most Ubuntu software** follows a 'snapshot' model. Once a new release of Ubuntu occurs, the software receives only security and serious bugfixes; no new releases. Example: 16.04 is two years old, and most software in 16.04 is also two years old.

**However**, ClamAV is one of the exceptions to that snapshot model. All supported releases of Ubuntu are upgraded to the latest ClamAV...after testing

**You DON'T need** to run the latest ClamAV to have the latest virus definitions. Like other AV products, ClamAV automatically updates those regardless of the application's version number.

Currently, 0.99.2 is the current ClamAV in ALL supported releases of Ubuntu. 0.99.3 is currently undergoing testing in 18.04 -proposed. When testing is complete, 0.99.3 will be rolled out to all supported releases of Ubuntu.

If you really need updated ClamAV *right now* (most folks don't), then go to the upstream ClamAV website and build from source instead of using the Ubuntu packages. Uninstall the Ubuntu packages before installing from another source to prevent conflicts and errors.

Comment: Are you aware that [until 0.99.3](http://blog.clamav.net/2018/01/clamav-0993-has-been-released.html), someone could just kill your server from remote: *The ClamAV AntiVirus software versions 0.99.2 and prior contain a vulnerability that could allow an unauthenticated, remote attacker to cause a denial of service (DoS) condition on an affected device.* Everyone needs this update **right now**.

Comment: @Mitja - you are mistaken. All supported releases of Ubuntu were patched for that vuln long ago. Proof: https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3393-1/ . Reminder: The version number is sometimes NOT a reliable indicator in Debian/Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, **you should run the latest ClamAV**, but sadly there is still no update available for Ubuntu.

All previous updates seem not to cover the 3 potential RCEs listed in the original ClamAV blog post - that's what CVEs are good for. Also note that 0.99.3-beta and 0.99.3-beta2 has nothing to do with the new 0.99.3.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clamav/+bug/1745635 for current update status.

Edit: to actually answer your question: you can either wait for an updated package or "roll your own" as there is no public PPA for ClamAV.

Comment: I don't have much technical knowledge to use Linux As Clamav has been presenting constant updating problems via the command line through freshclam I can use Clamtk it is all graphical and shows q updated the database I can trust Clamtk abandoning clamav and keep the system up to date? I deeply thank my colleagues for their attention Obs I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2