# How can I update ClamAV to 0.99.3?

Tags: clamav

When I try to run freshclam it will return to me:

```
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.99.2 Recommended version: 0.99.3
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Just wait until Ubuntu releases 0.99.3 soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clamav eternal suffer to update the version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999909/clamav-eternal-suffer-to-update-the-version)